# How do I sort a list with more than 1 item? I can only get it to sort the list with 1 item

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin

The code looks like this and as I mentioned in my title, the code works but only  with 1 item but I want it to search the list with an additional item.

This is my functional code (1 item named irl1):

```
private void FilterContacts(string filter)
{
    EmployeeList.BeginRefresh();

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter)) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("if1");
        EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourPitems;
    } else {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("else2");
        EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourPitems.Where(x => x.irl1.ToLower ().Contains (filter.ToLower ()));
    }

    EmployeeList.EndRefresh ();
}
```

and what I am trying to do does not work:

```
EmployeeList.ItemsSource = 
    ourPitems.Where(
        x => x.ourMadeUpNationality.ToLower(), 
        oem => oem.irl1.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())
    );
```

and while I'm at it, I tried to make the list refresh when I drag it up, but it just keeps loading, when I search in my list it updates. What I have tried to do is this but It does not seem to work.

```
public StartPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //add the refresh function here.

    EmployeeList.BeginRefresh();
    // this is for the search list.
    sbSearch.TextChanged += (sender2, e2) => FilterContacts(sbSearch.Text);
    // this is for the search list.
    sbSearch.SearchButtonPressed += (sender2, e2) => FilterContacts(sbSearch.Text);

    EmployeeList.EndRefresh();
}
```

Comment: Great humour! Sort a list (even successfully!) with one item.

Comment: it seems that you have asked two questions. its better to ask separate questions. one guy may know the answer to only on of your questions but then he cant answer because he does not fully answer your question and also others may down-vote him.

Comment: Yeah I maybe got ahead of myself there :P But the questions are kinda the same so I thought what the hell. Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: The list sorts itself perfectly now with the one item i have, i just want it to sort it by 2 different items !

Comment: btw you can use `&&` operator like. `x => x.ourMadeUpNationality.ToLower().Contains(...) && x.irl1.ToLower().Contains(....)` (and that guy is me ;) )

Comment: another note: `Where` does not sort. it filters data. i dont see where you want to sort. or maybe you used a wrong word?

Comment: In the first line you are saying you want to **"search the list with an addiotional item"**.
I am not sure if you are trying to search or sort but you can use `&&` and `||` operators something like this

`Users.Any(x => x.UserID == UserID && x.UserName == UserName)`

Comment: Do you mean _filter_ instead of _sort_? If so, please edit the question.

Comment: tried this code but did not work. no errors but now it finds nothing.
EmployeeList.ItemsSource = 
     ourPitems.Where 
     (x => x.ourMadeUpNationality.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower ()) && 
      x.irl1.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower ()));

Comment: "Where" worked before atleast. With 1 item and it could find the things on the list.

Comment: @DiddanDo are you looking for an `||` operator instead of `&&` ?

Comment: if you want to sort with more than 1 item then you have to use orderby after that thenby using linq , for eg: first you want to sort by date and after that you want to sort by time so you have to use .orderBy(date).ThenBy(tiime). Hope it will help for you.

Comment: I managed to solve it :) However I have another problem, I posted it here if u want to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465095/how-do-i-do-a-simple-ispulledtorefresh-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourPitems.Where(tk => tk.irl1.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower()) && tk.ourMadeUpNationality == "Test1");