# How do I do a simple isPulledToRefresh in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have isPulledToRefresh enabled (true) in my XAML and my listviews name is "EmployeeList". This code below that I have worked on does not work.

```
public static List<createSomething> ourPitems = new List <createSomething>();

public StartPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    loadOurList();
}

void loadOurList()
{
    EmployeeList.BeginRefresh();
    EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourPitems;
    EmployeeList.EndRefresh();
}
```

the "loading wheel" just keeps spinning.
(createSomething is my public class but i guess that I do not have to show that code).

Answer (score 0):

Just create a command to be executed when the user pulls the listview down:

```
public ICommand LoadDataCommand { get; set; }

public StartPage()
{ 
    ...
    BindingContext = this;
    LoadDataCommand = new Command(RefreshData);
    RefreshData();
}

private async void RefreshData()
{
    Items = new ObservableCollection<SomeItem>();  // Load Data and set
    IsRefreshing = false;
}

public ObservableCollection<SomeItem> Items { get; set; }
```

And in XAML, bind the command, your items, and the IsRefreshing Property:

```
<ListView x:Name="EmployeeList" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadDataCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

Comment: can't find : ICommand, ObservableCollection. gives me error because xamarin cant find it.

Comment: ICommand is in System.Windows.Input, but you can use Command (Xamarin.Forms) as well. ObservableCollection can be found in System.Collections.ObjectModel

Comment: Nop, does not work. Any idea where it might fail? The code itself runs but it doesnt get the result we are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a command and associate it to the ListView, 
I have an example in my Github https://github.com/Char0394/PullRefresh-XamarinForms-